# Batch script to copy latest log file from server to client system then rename it

Tags: file, logging, batch-file, xcopy, renaming

I am trying to setup a batch script that will copy over the latest IIS logs from our Exchange Client Access Server over to my system.  That way I can analyze the logs while keeping the original log file on the server.

So I need to have the script only copy over the latest log file then rename the log file to something like cas1Log.log

I know I have to use xcopy, I just can't figure out how to only copy the latest file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have permissions to access the folder, this should work:

```
@echo off
set "target=c:\local folder"
set "source=\\server\share\logfolder"
pushd "%source%"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.log /b /od /a-d') do set "logfile=%%a"
copy /b "%logfile%" "%target%\cas1Log.log"
popd
```

Comment: Thanks foxidrive! 

Now how do I rename the log file after it's been copied over to my computer?

To say cas1Logs.log

Comment: The copy command renames the file as it copies.  You need to change the c:\local folder\ to the place you want the file.

Comment: Yeah, I just didn't copy it correctly.

Lastly, is there a way to email myself this file via batch file?

Comment: See this for some samples, or google further.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/alt.msdos.batch.nt/lJS06Bs4iWE/mJH_XbS_mdwJ

Comment: Thanks for everything! :-D